# Finite measure extension on Baire $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, $\mu$ is finite measure on the Baire $\sigma$ algebra $B_{0}(X)$ ,then $\mu$ could be extended uniquely to a regular measure on $B(X)$.

I feel it's routine to use the Riesz representation theorem, but I just couldn't find how to use it. Now I sincerely ask for your help, any attempt would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the full answer. I know that $B_0(X)$ is generated by closed $G_\delta$ sets.  So $B_0(X)\subset  B(X)$.

In a simpler case where $X$ is metrizable we obtain that every that every closed subset $F$ of $X$ is $G_\delta$ because $F = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ where $A_n$ is the set of points $x$ of $X$ such that $d(x,F)<1/n$. Therefore in this case $B(X)=B_0(X)$ and the measure extension is trivial.